# How to get the size of pdf in bytes and assign it to the Data variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

i have defined the documentPicker like the following but i want now to get the size of the uploaded pdf in bytes.

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]){
self.parent.docData = // here the assigned value should be the size of the pdf

}
```

for example its working in case of image like the following:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
            let picdata = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.25)
            self.parent.picData = picdata!
            self.parent.picker.toggle()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
bcf.allowedUnits = [.useBytes]
bcf.countStyle = .file
let string = bcf.string(fromByteCount: Int64(picdata.count))`
Change unit of size as required in `[.useBytes]` this field. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response but since i assign the value `string` to the `self.parent.docData = string` it shows mismatching data type.

Comment: Obviously it is returning a string, Try `picdata.count` for assigning `data` value to another `data`.

Comment: picData it works, but i need to define docData like picData. i am getting in the case of your try zero bytes

Comment: Okay use below one to convert your picked up File converted into `data` `let data = try! Data(contentsOf: urls[0])` I think data is the data file created from your file picked by document Picker.

Comment: which one please? all what i want is, to get the size of the doc in bytes from the urls.first of the firestore and assign it to the self.parent.docData